# read_excel function is parsing the wrong columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table in excel

```
Year Quarter Reg orgID name s1 s2 s3
```

I am trying to read this table into python, only taking the columns orgID and s3, to do this I have tried

```
p = Path(directory)
#read file in
nf=pd.read_excel(p, parse_cols=[3,7])
```

but this is outputting just one column, but that column is Reg. Does anyone know why it would be selecting the wrong columns?

Comment: Are you using <21 pandas? See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html:
parse_cols : int or list, default None

Deprecated since version 0.21.0: Pass in usecols instead.

usecols : int or list, default None

If None then parse all columns,
If int then indicates last column to be parsed
If list of ints then indicates list of column numbers to be parsed
If string then indicates comma separated list of Excel column letters and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”). Ranges are inclusive of both sides.

Comment: When I use that I still get the same problem, only one column is outputted and it is the wrong column

Comment: And can you try/use excel ranges, ie letters "D,H" ?

Comment: I receive a value error if I try to use letters

ValueError: 'A' is not in list

Comment: For me this works just fine on my example excel, do you provide it with correct sheet_name?
`df = pd.read_excel(r"d:\_backup\big_excel.xlsx", usecols="A,B")
df.columns`
Index(['Project', 'TC Structure'], dtype='object')

Comment: I did think I was using the correct sheet. Turns out the creator of the spreadsheet decided to hide a sheet at the front (Facepalm)

Comment: it does. Thanks for your help, even if it was just my own naivety ...

Comment: I use this to select the sheet that you want to import `xl = pd.ExcelFile("file_name.xls")` `df = xl.parse("Sheet1")`